# java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to solve the error `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector` for the following case.

`gridEvalsRDD` is in the format `RDD[(Any,Any,Any,Double)]`, where the first `Any` is actually `Vectors.dense`.

I want to save `gridEvalsRDD` into the text file, which works fine for non-vector parameters. However, when I add `(%.3f,%.3f)`, it stops working.

```
gridEvalsRDD.coalesce(1)
            .map(e => "(%.3f,%.3f)\t%.3f\t%d\t%.3f".format(e._1, e._2, e._3, e._4))
            .saveAsTextFile("/data/mllib/streaming")
```

UPDATE:

The command `gridEvalsRDD.take(10).foreach(println)` gives the following output:

```
([0.0,0.0],0.1,25,75.75387778915743)
([0.0,0.0],0.1,50,59.6236379213822)
([0.0,0.0],0.2,25,46.98150325231958)
([0.0,0.0],0.2,50,34.53505034116878)
([0.0,0.0],0.3,25,33.497574283944445)
([0.0,0.0],0.3,50,23.03051323629829)
([10.0,10.0],0.1,25,2.6248163436296816)
([10.0,10.0],0.1,50,2.6248163436296816)
([10.0,10.0],0.2,25,2.6233782858570853)
([10.0,10.0],0.2,50,2.6233782858570853)
```

Comment: no Any is not a DenseVector, Any is Any

Comment: @eliasah: Ok, I agree with you. So the question is how to deal with `f != org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector`? If I put `"%.3f,\t%.3f\t%d\t%.3f"` or `"(%.3f,%.3f),\t%.3f\t%d\t%.3f"`, it doesn't work. However, if I exclude the first element (which indeed is a Vector), then everything works.

Comment: can you update your question with gridEvalsRDD.take(10).foreach(println) ?

Comment: @eliasah: Done. Please see my update.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: @eliasah: I want to format this data and save it to the text file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110513/discussion-between-eliasah-and-klue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a small discussion with you in chat, the issue lies in the way you are actually working with your parameters grid.

So, first, I'll re-defined my gridParams as an object and not a Map

```
object gridParams {
  val initialWeights: List[Vector] = List(Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0), Vectors.dense(10.0, 10.0))
  val stepSize: List[Double] = List(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
  val numIterations: List[Int] = List(25, 25)
}
```

Then I can compute the evaluations with the parameters :

```
val gridEvals: List[(Vector, Double, Int, Double)] = for (w <- gridParams.initialWeights;
                                                          s <- gridParams.stepSize;
                                                          itr <- gridParams.numIterations) yield {
     // some computation
     val accuracy: Double = 1.0
     (w, s, itr, accuracy)
}
```

If you want to convert the list to an RDD, go ahead, it seems rather small, so you can actually use plain Scala, as for the format now that we have error with, you can save them doing the following :

```
val gridEvalsRDD = sc.parallelize(gridEvals)
gridEvalsRDD.coalesce(1)
    .map(e => "%s\t%.3f\t%d\t%.3f".format(e._1.toString, e._2, e._3, e._4))
    .saveAsTextFile("./data/mllib/streaming")
```